# Disable WerFault.exe/"Application Has Stopped Working" crash dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-7, jit

I have a development tool that's crashing on launch, and I don't get to see any error messages it throws, or get a chance to debug it, because it shows the Windows 7 dialog for crashed programs, where it says "Windows is checking for a solution..."

I want to have my old school big ass assert dialog box back, with a big "DEBUG" button.  I have JIT completely enabled in Visual Studio's options and settings, so I'm not sure why I'm not getting the option.

[image]

Comment: Is your app built in Release or Debug mode?

Comment: Is this a managed program, or a native program?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[This blog post on raymond.cc](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-program-has-stopped-working-error-dialog-in-windows-server-2008/) contains an expanded version of the steps suggested in [Krzysztof John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21337282/1286571).

#### Quote:

> Turn Off The Error Dialog Via The Registry
>
> Although editing the registry manually is not recommended for average users, sometimes there isn’t a choice because something like the Group policy Editor might not be available in your version of Windows or the group policy method itself doesn’t work. This works on Windows Vista and above.
>
> 1. Open the Registry Editor by typing regedit into the Start search box or the Win+R Run dialog.
> 2. Navigate to the following registry key:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
>
> 3. Double click the DontShowUI entry on the right and change its value to 1, then close the registry editor.
>
> . . .
>
> The above registry fix will turn off the popup dialog for the current user, if you want the setting to affect all users on the computer then a similar registry key needs to be created in the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. This key isn’t present by default so needs to be created.

Read More: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-program-has-stopped-working-error-dialog-in-windows-server-2008/

Answer (score 18):

Use Regedit, navigate to the below path:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\DontShowUI] 
Create a DWORD and set the value to 1.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Are there other dialogs that this setting controls?

Answer (score 3):

control panel -> troubleshooting -> change settings

Comment: Could you elaborate? My system is in Polish and I'm not sure if I see the right settings.

Comment: If you're able to get to the Troubleshooting section of control panel, "change settings" will be in the sub nav menu on the left side of the window.  From there you should see a radio on the top half of the screen, set to "On(Recommended)".  Switch it to "off" and programs will crash the way they're supposed to.

Comment: // , This worked for me in Windows 7. What a relief. @Mauricio Scheffer, would you be willing to post a link to a question like this that is for Winblows 8.1 instead of Winblows 7?

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. "There is a misconception that you can disable the program has stopped working popup through the Action center in Windows Control Panel. ... The stopped working popup will still appear but with or without the check for solutions option," https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-program-has-stopped-working-error-dialog-in-windows-server-2008/

Answer (score 1):

In my case this solved same problem:
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Action Center\Problem Reporting Settings
set to "never check for solutions"

Answer (score 1):

On my old Windows Vista Home Basic install, the option is hidden in a completely different place beneath the control panel:

**Control Panel → Classic View → Problem Reports and Solutions → Change Settings → Advanced Settings → “For my programs, problem reporting is: [×] Off”**