# Selenium how to close Internet Explorer has stopped working

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am screen scraping a legacy website that uses activex controls.  I am using selenium to accomplish this.

This website is buggy and whenever you signout of it, it crashes IE and you get the "Internet Explorer has stopped working" window.  This happens no matter what, website needs to be recoded.

Is there a way in InternetExplorerDriver.Quit() to detect if this window is up and close it?  The annoyance is that while the dialog is doing "searching for a solution..." it doesn't release selenium, so my code hangs up waiting.

Right now I am attempting to kill the process through the windows api, but that requires waiting for selenium to finish closing.

Comment: Fix the application :)

Comment: This is a solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875518/how-do-i-disable-program-has-stopped-working-dialog-in-windows-7  It may not be the best.

Answer (score 0):

The solution Richard posted in the comments worked.  I just told windows to stop checking for solutions.